# Uso de Side NavBar Materialize CSS

Tags: html5, css3, materialize

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Boa noite,

estou criando um crud e usando materialize no front, como sou iniciante estou com um pequeno problema, como faço pra "linkar"as sessões do side? tipo, quando clicar em produtos tem que aparecer do lado na parte em branco uma lista de produtos, cadastrar do mesmo jeito, assim que clicar iria aparecer um form pra cadastro, estou com dificuldade pra definir isso, terei que gerar outros doc .html? tipo, produto.html e abri-lo? se sim, como faço pra abrir no espaço abaixo? obrigado :D

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma de se fazer é criando vários arquivos e linkando eles com a tag `<a href='caminho/da_pagina/produtos.html'>Produtos</a>`, se não me engano os itens do menu ficam em tags `<li> </li>`

Comment: era exatamente  isso minha  duvida, entao pra cada item na  side terei que  criar um arquivo html, certo?

Comment: Sim, essa é a forma mais simples, mas pesquise por Single Page Aplication